# How do you squeeze a hydraulic floor jack and a jack stand one next to the other?

Tags: jack-stand, hydraulic, floor-jack

The Owner's Manual of vehicles will point to spots where one can safely lift a car.

Yet the safe usage (not an option if one will be under the car) is to lift with a hydraulic floor jack **and** to use a jack stand. The base of the jack stand is quite large (as it needs to be).

How does one come up with *two* spots in the chassis (for each wheel), one for the hydraulic floor jack and another for the jack stand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's been a tough call for me for every vehicle lift. Once the vehicle is elevated, the jack stands can be slid under the vehicle, aiming for a portion of the suspension that does not compress when the vehicle is on the ground.

I've used leaf spring hanger brackets as a contact point for the jack stand, as the bracket is obviously mounted to the frame.

If the vehicle has a solid axle, there's an easy answer. I have a FWD vehicle without a solid axle and the pivot point for the suspension, which is located quite a bit inboard, will provide for a secure rest for the stand.